# Unpack ISO image, edit some files, repack an ISO so that it still boots

Tags: boot, live-cd, iso

So I've used the `live-build` tools with some success. An ISO is generated, it loads in Virtualbox but fails to boot because the config file is looking for vmlinuz.lz but `binary/casper` contains:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 243769344 Jan 10 13:32 filesystem.squashfs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        10 Jan 10 13:32 filesystem.size
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8549 Jan 10 13:32 filesystem.manifest
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      1227 Jan 10 13:32 filesystem.manifest-remove
-rw------- 1 root root   5814080 Jan 10 13:32 vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24011791 Jan 10 13:32 initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    176500 Jan 10 13:32 memtest
```

My plan is to rename the files vmlinuz* and initrd.* to have the names stored within the config file, and then repackage the ISO.

My questions:

1. By renaming the files do I need to recreate the manifest? If so how?
2. How can I either manually unpack the ISO, make these edits and pack it up again so that it still boots?

Comment: For some reason, no one tries to answer the question about re-packing Ubuntu on askubuntu. I have no idea why!

Answer (score 0):

Install isohybrid:

sudo apt install syslinux-utils

Then simply type the following to make it bootable:

sudo isohybrid output.iso